# Macro opening old workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a workbook that is an updated copy of an older workbook. *When I run the macro in the new workbook, it seems to run just fine BUT it also opens the old workbook.* I would like this not to happen.

- The new workbook is called **LOG.xlsm**.
- The old workbook is called **Application Log-Macro.xlsm**. It is in the same folder as the new workbook.
- I'm running Excel 2016.

Please help me out here --  I'm guessing I need to change the code to make sure the active workbook is LOG.xlsm??

Here is the code:

```
Sub SortApps()
'
' SortApps Macro
Application.Goto Reference:="AppsTable"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("AppsTable[NOTES]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields _
    (1).SortOnValue
    .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
    .Gradient.Degree = 0
    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields _
    (1).SortOnValue.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
    .Color = 16763391
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields _
    (1).SortOnValue.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
    .Color = 16738047
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("AppsTable[NOTES]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields _
    (2).SortOnValue
    .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
    .Gradient.Degree = 180
    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields _
    (2).SortOnValue.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
    .Color = 3394611
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields _
    (2).SortOnValue.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
    .Color = 3407718
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields.Add( _
    Range("AppsTable[STAT]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(204, 0, 102)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields.Add( _
    Range("AppsTable[STAT]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(204, 153, 255)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("AppsTable[T2]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:= _
    xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields _
    (5).SortOnValue
    .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
    .Gradient.Degree = 270
    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields _
    (5).SortOnValue.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
    .Color = 14202006
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields _
    (5).SortOnValue.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
    .Color = 9592886
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields.Add( _
    Range("AppsTable[NOTES]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlDescending, , xlSortNormal). _
    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(218, 238, 243)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields.Add( _
    Range("AppsTable[STAT]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields.Add( _
    Range("AppsTable[RI DUE]"), xlSortOnFontColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields.Add( _
    Range("AppsTable[STAT]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(247, 150, 70)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields.Add( _
    Range("AppsTable[STAT]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 235, 156)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("AppsTable[APP DT]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("AppsTable[SSN]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Apps").ListObjects("AppsTable").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Range("K9").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=21
Range("AppsTable[NOTES]").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-39
Selection.Rows.AutoFit
Range("A9").Select
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your advice! I'm sure it's something easy but it's throwing me for a loop, because (surprise) I don't actually know what the heck I'm doing. :")

Comment: Are you sure you are running the macro in the new workbook?  (If, for instance, you have a button to invoke the macro, and you left that button invoking `'Application Log-Macro.xlsm'!SortApps`, then the first thing that pressing the button will do is open `Application Log-Macro.xlsm`.)

Comment: @YowE3K - Good thinking, that is exactly what the problem was. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you copied sheets from the old workbook when creating the new workbook, there may be an internal reference to the old workbook in your new one.  First rule out that possibility by following the instructions here.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-links-external-references-in-a-workbook-fcbf4576-3aab-4029-ba25-54313a532ff1

Comment: TYSM for your help. It turns out that the issue was that I was using a Quick Access button from the old workbook to run the macro, but I think your advice will be helpful for a different workbook I'm working with right now.